# How can I plot a line chart with two different companies monthly sales from 12 months before and 12 months after

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

The dataframe is a snapshot of what I'm working with. What I want to achieve is a line chart of the monthly sales of the different brands. Months with '-' before the number indicates the months prior up to 12 months prior and months without '-' before the number indicates months after also up to 12 months. On the line chart, all the '-' months(prior months) will be on the left and the months after will be on the right with 0 as center. Count_Toy_Brand_A is the count of different Toy_Brands at company A whereas Count_Toy_Brand_B is the count of different TOY_Brands at company B. In total I'm going to end up with three different line chart for A,B,C with two lines each labelled Company A and Company B. I was wondering if this can be done in pandas. Any help would be appreciated. Attached is a snapshot of the output I'm looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'toy_brand_A':['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'count_toy_brand_A':[11, 5, 16],
    'month-0_sales_A':[50, 12, 6],
    'month-1_sales_A':[8,7, 6],
    'month-2_sales_A':[8,7, 6],
    'month1_sales_A':[20, 40, 18],
    'month2_sales_A':[8,7, 6],
    'count_toy_brand_B':[15, 25, 4],
    'month-0_sales_B':[10, 8, 61],
    'month-1_sales_B':[3,5, 90],
    'month-2_sales_B':[4,7, 1],
    'month1_sales_B':[30, 20, 18],
    'month2_sales_B':[8,7, 6],
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reformat the data first:

```
# Removes unnecessary columns and sets new indices.
cols = df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains('count')]
df = df[cols]
df.rename(columns={'toy_brand_A': 'toy_brand'}, inplace=True)
df.set_index('toy_brand', inplace=True)
df = df.T
df['company'] = 0
df.loc[df.index.str.contains('_A'), 'company'] = 'A'
df.loc[df.index.str.contains('_B'), 'company'] = 'B'
df.index = df.index.str.replace('_A', '')
df.index = df.index.str.replace('_B', '')
```

Output:

```
toy_brand       A   B   C   company
month-0_sales   50  12  6   A
month-1_sales   8   7   6   A
month-2_sales   8   7   6   A
month1_sales    20  40  18  A
month2_sales    8   7   6   A
month-0_sales   10  8   61  B
```

Plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
for i, brand in enumerate(['A', 'B', 'C']):
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
    data = df[[brand, 'company']].reset_index()
    s = sns.lineplot(data=data, x='index', y=brand, hue='company', ax=ax)
    s.set_xticklabels(a.index, rotation=45, ha='right')
    s.set_xlabel('months', fontsize=20)
    s.set_ylabel(f'Sales brand {brand}', fontsize=20)
    s.set_title('My Title')
    
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your input, I really appreciate your help. But I'm getting the error 'NameError: name 'a' is not defined'(s.set_xticklabels(a.index, rotation=45, ha='right')) ' when I run the plot part. Please do you have any idea why that is happening? Thanks

Comment: I think I fixed it, changed the 'a' to df and it worked.  But is there a way to make 'month 0' the center between the -ve months and +ve months?

Comment: And also on the chart it starts from the lowest value in this case 'month-2' to 0 to 'month2'

Comment: @SeanjeeWatara, a good way would be to rename the month names to datetime format, and then sort by index.